# Can you use remove.(this) for an ArrayList inside an Object instance?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

If I had an static ArrayList called foo which held Objects called ServerThread, would I be able to call 
`foo.remove(this)`
from within a ServerThread instance to remove itself from that ArrayList?

Comment: as a side note you probably don't want to be using an arraylist if there are a lot of removes going on.

Comment: Yes. But from what you said, you will probably want to synchronize the List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what [ArrayList#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) (and `List#remove` generally) is for. Be sure that if you have this list shared with multiple threads, you do any appropriate locking/synchronization to make sure you don't modify it in one thread when you're iterating it in another, etc.

---

And as Woot4Moo pointed out in the comments, `ArrayList` may not be the ideal choice if you're doing a lot of removes. You might consider `LinkedList`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for mentioning synchronization or else I would have completely forgot to consider that in my implementation, would
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList(...));
be the efficient approach then?

Comment: @Matrix159: That would synchronize *everything*, which might be more expensive than needed, but other than that... Also note that if you're iterating over the list, even with the result of `synchronizedList`, you still have to explicitly synchronize on the list instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you look at the source code for `ArrayList#remove(Object)`, you will see that it uses `equals`. More generally, that's exactly what you'd use `ArrayList#remove(Object)` for; to remove a particular instance of an object (if it exists in the list).

The manner in which you are using the list is a little bit concerning. You might want to be sure that you guard access to the list if you are manipulating it from multiple threads.

---

As pointed out in the comments, you might not want to use `ArrayList` if you are doing a lot of removes. This is because overall it is an `O(n)` operation since you have to find the element you want in the array that backs `ArrayList`, and then shift all the other elements up. However for `LinkedList`, you only have to find the element (which *can* be an `O(n)` in the worst case but that shouldn't happen most of the time).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not.  I guess your doubt is because it seems like the thread is 'committing suicide' by removing the reference to itself.  But there is no special behaviour when passing 'this' in as a function argument...it is just an object in the list like any other.